# How to find fields in configuration forms in magento?

Tags: forms, magento, backend, hint

I want edit fields in shipping methods in backend in magento but I can not find where are fields, I used template path hints but I can not find, how can I find forms elements in backend in magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento system configuration fields are generated from `system.xml`.

We can create `system.xml` file for each module, but we need to place that in
`app/code/local/namespace/module/etc/`

Refer this [**Link**](http://inchoo.net/magento/create-configuration-for-your-magento-extension/) to know more about this